# how to remove the previous rows values in the newly added rows in jsp using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

i have a table with single row and with the buttons add and remove along with each row....if you press add button then it will add new row but the problem is if you fill the 1st row with some values and then if you press the add button then the new row coming with that values.....i dont want like that,,the new rows should come with empty values....can any one resolve this???

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableSize=0;
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    $clone_row = $('#FirstRow').clone(true);
    $clone_row.appendTo('#listfiles');
    var row_len = $('#listfiles tr').length;
    var file_name = 'File ' + row_len + ':';
    $clone_row.find('span.file_name').text(file_name);

   });
 });

function deleteRow(btn) {

tableSize = $('#listfiles tr').length;
if (tableSize > 1) {
$(btn).parent().parent().remove();
$('#listfiles tr').each(function (i) {
    var index = i + 1;
    $('td:first .file_name', this).text('File ' + index + ':');
 })
 }
 }
 </script>
  </head>
 <body>
 table id="listfiles">
 <tr id="FirstRow">
    <td>    <span class="file_name">File 1:</span>

        <input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" value="xyz" />Description:
        <input type="text" name="description" id="filename" value="" />
     <a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(this);">DeleteFile</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
 </table> <a href="#" id="btnAdd">Add additional file</a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$clone_row = $('#FirstRow').clone();
$cloned_row.find("input").val('');
```

Comment: Where you are adding $cloned_row.find("input").val(''); line?

Comment: You need to do $cloned_row.find("input").val(''); before appendTo

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        $clone_row = $('#FirstRow').clone(true);
        $cloned_row.find("input").val('')
        $clone_row.appendTo('#listfiles');
        var row_len = $('#listfiles tr').length;
        var file_name = 'File ' + row_len + ':';
        $clone_row.find('span.file_name').text(file_name);

    });

Comment: i need it like you know after you select a particular file by clicking on browse button then the button should be replace with the selected file path....can you please do this???

Comment: check that once again its taking the same path if you add new row once...i mean if select a particular file then if you press add button for new row then it is nt showign browse button even in the newly added rows..